# Is this right way to call a function in c++?

Tags: c++

```
Time t (12, 0, 0); t.GetTime();

Time* t = new Time(12, 0, 0); t->GetTime();
```

Is this Correct way to call a method using object that are created without new keyword and with new keyword???
Thanks..

Comment: Well, yes, apparently, at least syntactically. But what did your C++ book say about that?

Comment: Both are equivalent, with the exception that the second may cause a memory leak if you don't `delete` the object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Excerpt 1**

```
Time t (12, 0, 0);
```

Since `t` is a struct or class of type `Time`, you access its members with the `.` operator, known as *element selection by reference*.

```
t.GetTime();
```

**Excerpt 2**

```
Time* t = new Time(12, 0, 0);
```

Here, `t` is a pointer to `Time` and so you can first de-reference the pointer and then use the `.` operator like before:

```
(*t).GetTime();
```

Or the short cut way that you used, which uses the *element selection through pointer* operator, `->`:

```
t->GetTime();
```

---

As Armin correctly points out, the form of element access that you need to use is determined by the type of the variable through which you access the element. It is not determined by the way in which the object is created. For example:

```
Time t1 (12, 0, 0);
Time *t2 = &t1; 
t1.GetTime();
t2->GetTime();
(&t1)->GetTime();
(*t2).GetTime();
```

Comment: +1. I would add a sentence to your great answer which explicitly says that the way the object was created has nothing to do with element acess (perhaps adding an example like Time t; Time* pt = &t; pt->GetTime();

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the two are that the first allocates memory on the stack and the second on the heap:

```
Time t (12, 0, 0); //t is an object on the stack
Time* t = new Time(12, 0, 0);//t is a pointer to an object on the heap
```

Note that using the second way requires a call to:

```
delete t;
```

when you finish using it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Time class and GetTime function inside it, It's Correct but you should release the memory by
delete t for 2nd one, because it's not deleted automatically